# How to get R to deal with a 0 value in your dependent variable when you want to log your distribution

Tags: r, dataset, skewness

I have a heavily positive distribution in my dataset of my x variable, the aim to put the variable into 4 categories of categorical variable. Although, my initial idea is to log the continuous data then split it into categories. However, lots of values of the dependent variable are 0 which then would require a constant in the log transformation.
Is it appropriate to just split a positive skewed dataset into a categorical variable rather than transforming the data first.

Regards,
Otis

Comment: Check out `hurdle` and `zeroinfl` in the pscl package.

Comment: Why do you want to put your x variable into categories? That's [not generally a good idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500). Please provide your reasons for categorization by editing your question, as comments are sometimes ignored and can be lost.

Comment: Also, if x is categorical there is no need to take the log of y.